# Transparent background makes my text transparent too

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am making a text box with black transparent background and I want the text to not be transparent, but it makes my text transparent too. Can someone tell me where i made a mistake ?

style.css

```
#headertxt  {
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
bottom: 100px;
background-size: auto;
background: black;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70); 
 }

 #headertxt a {
text-align: right;
color: white;
}
```

html :

```
   <div id="headertxt">
    <a>Zvani <span class="head"> (+371) 29 256 487</span><br /></a>
     <a>  Raksti <span class="head"><ahref="mailto:info@bukdangas.lv">info@bukdangas.lv</a></span><br /></a>
     <a>Redzi mūs <span class="head"><a href="/ka-mus-atrast/">kartē</a>
      <br/></a>
        <a><span class="head">N 57° 11' 22" E 22° 12' 46"</span><br />  </a>
                    <hr>
                    <a>REKVIZĪTI</a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`opacity` and `filter` is applied to the whole element. You need to switch to `rgba` format for the background. It should be:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

and get rid of `opacity` and `filter`.